# yii: Append instead of replace items in CListView when using pager

Tags: php, yii, yii-components

I'm using CListView widget to render by items.

But now when I change the page using pagers provided by CListView, it change the data in the _view.

I'd like to know if I can obtain the old data (says, page 1) and append the new data (page 2) to it so that I can see both data from page 1 and page 2.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an extension for yii which provides an endless scrolling pagination: http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yiinfinite-scroll/

Comment: Thanks! But I can't figure out how to use that extension. I use its widget in my view and render my items using for-loops, but it didn't work as infinite-scroll. Is there any sample code? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately I've never used it for myself, but I'm sure you'll get an answer in the yii forums.